# Why is the following true about compact spaces?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Here's the problem

> Let $X$ be a topological space. A family $(V_i)_{i∈I}$ of subsets of $X$ is said to have the finite
>   intersection property if for all finite $J ⊆ I$, the intersection $\cap
> _{j∈J}
> V_j$ is nonempty.
>   Prove that $X$ is compact if and only if it has the following property: for every family
>   $(V_i)_{i∈I}$ of closed subsets with the finite intersection property, $\cap
> _{i∈I}
> V_i$
>   is nonempty

Now, please note I am not a big fan of compactness. I'm trying to get used to it. That being said, I came up with an odd conclusion.

My understanding of a compact space is that

> $X$ is compact if for every open covering, there is a finite subcovering.

And an open covering is just a union of open subsets of $X$.

So, well, if I assume that every family of "closed" subsets of $X$ has the finite intersection property... I concluded that $X$ can't have a bunch of open coverings.

Because, say $V_i,V_j$ are distinct closed subsets of $X$. By the said property, the intersection is non empty. Equivalently, they share at least one element of $X$. Equivalently, $(X＼V_i) \cup (X＼V_j)$ will have a "hole" which is the part that $V_i,V_j$ have in common. So, since every open subset of $X$ must be in the form $X＼V_i$, the union of them will always have a "hole" because the closed subsets are guaranteed to have some element in common, whichever and how many I choose to intersect.

And this "hole" there means that $X$ is not covered how ever many I gather $X＼V_i$s around. That one hole cannot be covered by open subsets. Therefore, even before considering finite subcoverings, $X$ does not have an open covering.

Well, clearly my conclusion "should" be wrong. Problem, is, where and why. I drew a picture with just $2$ closed subsets of $X$ in $X$ but indeed I get a hole in the picture.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Take complements in the definition of compactness.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: lack of some conditons for the statement? Your reasoning is reasonable with the current assumptions.

Comment: really....? That really is the full question I am given, and it's odd I've reasoned so that I've proved that the statement isn't true.. there must be something wrong with my argument

Comment: You might miss the "for every" statement. If X is compact, you need to prove, for every ${V_i}}$ with finite intersection property leads to $\cap
_{i∈I}
V_i$ is not empty.  Also, in other direction, you need to use the asummption "for every" such collection of sets, to prove X is compact. You just find one type of collections of such sets is not enough to prove X is compact. You need to find a special one as other answers stated. In plain words, you have not found a special sucn set to warrant X is compact in your reasoning.

Comment: (1)An open covering $X$ of  is not the union of a collection of open subsets of $X$. An open covering (or cover) of $X$ is a set $C$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $\cup C=X.$ ...(2) In the def'n of FIP, it must state that $J$ is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with your reasoning is that you are starting from the assumption that every family of closed subsets of $X$ has the finite intersection property and drawing some correct but (to you) surprising conclusions from that assumption. The problem is asking you to assume that any family of closed subsets that happens to have the finite intersection property has a non-empty intersection, not that every family of closed sets actually does have the finite intersection property.

[PS: persevere! compactness is really cool!]

Comment: Thanks, i might've gotten closer to the correct way of thinking, but can I ask you to make one more step clearer though? I'm just thinking, isn't it "having the finite intersection property"="has a non-empty intersection"? Because, it sounds like there could be cases where it has the finite intersection property but the intersections can be empty too. As "if my head hurts i have a headache" but in some cases " my head hurts but i don't have a headache" can be true.  And thanks a lot for the encouraging comment :)

Comment: Consider the subspace $X = (0, 1]$ of $\Bbb{R}$. The intervals $V_i = (0,1/i], i = 1, 2, \ldots$ comprise a set of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property but with an empty intersection. If you look at their complements, i.e., the sets  $W_i = (1/i, 1]$, you will find they form an open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover. These possibilities arise because $X$ is not compact.

Comment: ... and the traditional way of talking about this is rather confusing: to define compactness in terms of open sets we say "any open cover has a finite subcover". The direct way of saying that in terms of closed sets would be to say "any family of closed sets with an empty intersection has a finite subfamily with an empty intersection", but the traditional way of saying that is to recast it as "any family of closed sets whose finite subfamilies don't have empty intersections doesn't have an empty intersection" (and to abbreviate the hypothesis using the concept of finite intersection property).

Answer (score 2):

$X$ is compact i.e for every open covering, $(U_i)_{i\in I}$, there exists a finite subset $J\subset I$ such that $(U_j)_{j\in J}$ cover $X$. Set $C_i$ is the complementary of $U_i$ you obtain:

$X$ is compact if and only if given a family of closed subsets $(C_i)_{i\in I}$ of $X$ such that $\cap_iC_i=\phi$, there exists a finite subset $J\subset I$ such that $\cap_{j\in J}C_j=\phi$.

You know that $p$ implies $q$ is equivalent to the negation of $q$ implies the negation of $p$ so

The contraposition of this definition is for every family $(V_i)_{i\in I}$ if you have for every finite subset $J\subset I$ $\cap_{j\in J}C_j\neq \phi$ then $\cap_{i\in I}C_i\neq \phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $X$ is not compact, then there is an open cover $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X$ such that no finite subcollection covers $X$.

Let $F_i=X\setminus V_i$, then $F_i$ is closed, and each finite intersection
$$ F_{i_1}\cap\dots\cap F_{i_n}=X\setminus (V_{i_1}\cup\cdots\cup V_{i_n})$$
is non-empty because $V_{i_1}\cup\dots V_{i_n}$ doesn't cover $X$. But
$$ \bigcap_{i\in I}F_i=X\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i=\emptyset $$
because the $V_i$ cover $X$. So $X$ does not have the finite intersection property.

The converse works the same way.

Comment: Hi, I think you've helped answer the question itself, but the core issue is, what is wrong with my reasoning...? Because in mine, I came to say that "no open coverings exist" on $X$.

Comment: I think the issue is that $X\setminus V_i$ is closed, not open. There certainly always exist open coverings of $X$, e.g. $\{X\}$.

Comment: $X＼V_i$ is closed? But I thought by definition, $V_i$ being closed means its complement must be open. Can a set be closed and its complement be also closed in topology?

Comment: I think we're disagreeing on notation: I took the $V_i$ to be open.

Comment: But more importantly, yes a set can be open and closed. $X$ and $\emptyset$ are two examples.

Comment: I think $(V_i)$ is supposed to be a family of closed subsets of $X$ as stated in the question. So $V_i$ must be closed. But okay, even if $X＼V_i$ IS closed (I don't know how to deduce whether it is closed or open in this case), what changes? The set $X$ is made of $V_i$ and $X＼V_i$. So if both are closed, then that means...$X$ is closed? but it's also open...god this is just too vague I cannot draw any conclusions :/

Answer (score 1):

You are right that for two *intersecting* closed sets, their complements are *not* a cover of $X$. Note that we can reverse this to: *if* we have a finite open cover of $X$, their complements form a finite family of closed sets with empty intersection. So far so good.

Now what compactness means is that for *every* open cover, we can find a finite subfamily that is *also* an open cover. So we have to show that for *every* family of closed sets with *empty* intersection (which is not every family of closed sets, of course!) there is a finite subfamily which *also* has an empty intersection. This follows by the same complements reasoning.

So if $X$ is compact, we also know that last fact about families of closed sets: if we happen to have an empty intersection then this means some **finite** empty intersection of a subset. So if we assume the latter never happens (which we call the finite intersection property), the former also never happens. This is the basic idea.